# OctoPrint API, error 400 when making a POST request

Tags: python, api, python-requests, octoprint

I'm working with [Octoprint's API](https://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/index.html). I'm struggling trying to issue commands to the 3d printer.

For example, I want to issue a command that makes the 3d printer jog the X-axis.

```py
import requests
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"}

def Beep():
  api_link = "http://octopi.local/api/printer/command"
  params = {"command":"jog","x":10}
  return requests.post(api_link, headers=headers, params=params)
```

The output of this code is <Response 400> (bad request). What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API documentation:

> If not otherwise stated, OctoPrint’s API expects request bodies and issues response bodies as `Content-Type: application/json`.

Your request is not sending JSON.  Use this instead:

```
requests.post(api_link, headers=headers, json=params)
```

Also, it looks like the `jog` command is supposed to use the url path `/api/printer/printhead`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Yes, you're right about the jog command, I just copy-pasted without looking! Thank you!